# Subscript out of range - How do I get more detail

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have some vba code in Excel causing an issue (the code itself is not relevant to the purpose of this question)

When the code runs I get the following error message

> Subscript out of range

That's it. Nothing else.

In Visual Studio when some thing breaks, I get a call stack, the debugger moves the faulty line of code in question etc and debugging can be very simple.

My question is what can I do to find out more about this issue other than attempting to step through the code line at a time.

Is there a way to make VBa stop on the line which causes the error. Or shows this in one of the windows/panels, like an exception panel.

Comment: Have you tried hitting CTRL+Break when the error message pops up? This will often open the VBE to the line that caused the error.

Answer (score 1):

IN VBA, when an error occurs:

[image]

click <kbd>Debug</kbd> to see the error:

[image]